# Manually change Numeric parameters for OLAP formula

Tags: excel, powerbi, olap-cube

I had created a Pivot which uses Power Bi model as it's data source (Analysis services). Since my data is huge and there limitations of pivot, I am exploring other ways of pulling the data.

I converted the sample Pivot to Olap Formula and I think this is the best solution from all the options I have explored. But there is some odd situation I am facing where I need some help.

I tweaked the structure as shown below. So now whenever I change any string like in the below example if I manually change the currency from SGD to USD, I am getting the result. But whenever I try to Manually change any numeric value like Segment, I am getting #N/A. The same numbers when pulled using pivot gives the number.

[image]

[image]

I have tried to insert the numeric value in following ways

```
40
'40
="40"
=text("40",0)
text to columns->text
```

but till now I am not able to crack this.

Comment: Have you tried =40+0  ???

Comment: The documentation has info regarding NA# error that may be useful. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cubevalue-function-8733da24-26d1-4e34-9b3a-84a8f00dcbe0

Answer (score 0):

The [cubevalue](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/cubevalue-function-8733da24-26d1-4e34-9b3a-84a8f00dcbe0) function expects dimensions on which it is going to filter the values. If you want to provide the value manually you'll have to do it like this:

=CUBEVALUE("Sales","[Measures].[Profit]","[Time].[2004]","[All Product].[Beverages]")

Meaning you'll have to change the `40` to something like `[MyDimension].[MyHierarchy].[40]`